# How to comment a block in MATLAB, similar in C /**/

Tags: matlab, comments

I want to know how to comment a block in MATLAB. I know that in the C language I use `/ *`; But I could not find out about MATLAB.

Comment: Alternatively you can select a multiple lines of code and 'comment' those Ctrl-R/Cmd-R and un-comment Ctrl-T/Cmd-T. I think those are the default shortcuts.

Comment: Inform yourself please before asking... Googling should definitely help here!

Answer (score 7):

You can comment out MATLAB blocks with

```
%{
  Comments go here
%}
Outside comment
```

Comment: Thank you Chinny84